# How to use makefile to compile and update all files in one folder independently

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I have a folder containing several .cpp files, e.g. A.cpp, B.cpp and C.cpp. They are all independent from each other. I could compile A.cpp to A.o and then to binary file A. So it is with B.cpp and C.cpp.

I want to write a makefile that could compile all these files at once. And in the future, if there are some new files such as D.cpp is put into this folder, makefile can still handle it automatically.

My current file is

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=$(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=$(SOURCES:.cpp=)

all: $(SOURCES) $(OBJECTS) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)  
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(@:.o=.cpp) -o $@

$(EXECUTABLE): $(SOURCES)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(@:=.o) -o $@
```

The problem is that once one .cpp file is changed or added into the folder, all other files will be updated and re-compiled if I do make.

Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your makefile lists every source file as a prerequisite of every executable and every object file.

It also doesn't like the object files as prerequisites of the executables (which means make can't automatically build them for you).

Those are the problems.

That all being said you don't need the rules in this makefile at all.

A makefile of just

```
CC=g++
CXXFLAGS=-c -Wall
```

will let you run `make A` and build `A` from `A.cpp` (though it won't build `A.o` to do that since it doesn't need to). You don't even need a makefile at all to build `A` from `A.cpp` if you don't need to set `CC` or `CXXFLAGS` (or don't mind setting them on the command line.

```
$ mkdir test
$ cd test
$ ls
$ touch A.cpp
$ make CC=g++ CXXFLAGS='-c -Wall' A
g++ -c -Wall    A.cpp   -o A
```

But if you ask it to make `A.o` it will.

```
$ make CC=g++ CXXFLAGS='-c -Wall' A.o
g++ -c -Wall   -c -o A.o A.cpp
```

At which point make will try to build `A` from `A.o`.

```
$ make CC=g++ CXXFLAGS='-c -Wall' A
g++   A.o   -o A
```

To get back support for `make` building all the executables you need a line like:

```
all: $(subst .cpp,,$(wildcard *.cpp))
```

If you *do* want to manually specify everything nonetheless (and force `.o` building) you want something more like this. (Which uses [10.5 Defining and Redefining Pattern Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules) and [4.12 Static Pattern Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern).)

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=$(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=$(SOURCES:.cpp=)

all: $(EXECUTABLE)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

$(EXECUTABLE): % : %.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

Which then lets you write `make` to build them all and `make A` to build specific ones.

Answer (score 1):

Put `.SUFFIXES: .o .cpp` in above of `all` line.

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=$(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=$(SOURCES:.cpp=)

.SUFFIXES: .o .cpp

all: $(SOURCES) $(OBJECTS) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)  
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(@:.o=.cpp) -o $@

$(EXECUTABLE): $(SOURCES)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(@:=.o) -o $@
```

**Additional**

Use this

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=$(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=$(SOURCES:.cpp=)

.SUFFIXES: .o .cpp

all: $(EXECUTABLE)

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(@:.o=.cpp) -o $@

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@
```

You don't need to put $(SOURCES) or $(OBJECTS) into `all`. you must write below

`DESTINATION: SOURCE`

For about `.SUFFIXES` and `.cpp.o`, it's an especially. it works as `.SOURCE.DESTINATION:`

Comment: No, that doesn't fix the problems here.

Comment: do you mean header files?

Comment: I mean that `$(EXECUTABLE): $(SOURCES)` is wrong on a number of levels. `$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)` is also wrong. And those are causing the problem.

Comment: i'm reading the link https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html which gives me some ideas on the Suffix Rules. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to change your `all:` line, and then remove all the other lines that follow it.

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=$(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=$(SOURCES:.cpp=)

all: $(OBJECTS) $(EXECUTABLE)
```

If you don't need to create the `.o` files, then you can also remove `$(OBJECTS)` from `all:`, as well as the line that defines it. This removes the need to redefine `$(CC)` for the link line, but you need to add `-Wall` to `$(CXXFLAGS)`.

```
CXXFLAGS=-Wall
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=$(wildcard *.cpp)
EXECUTABLE=$(SOURCES:.cpp=)

all: $(EXECUTABLE)
```

Comment: this example only works if the 'std' make initialization file is available.  And it does not properly handle changes in header files, nor if the user header files are in a different directory from the current directory.  and without a .PHONY: all line, it will complain that it cannot create the 'all' file

Comment: @user3629249: I grant this is not a general solution to makefiles. It is directed at this particular question.

Comment: `.PHONY: all` is only necessary to keep make from doing nothing should an `all` file come into existence. make will not give an error about being unable to create an `all` file without it... at least in `GNU Make 3.81` it is possible newer versions added that sanity check.

Answer (score 1):

The two lines giving you grief are:

```
$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(SOURCES)
```

The first says "every object file depends on every one of the source files; if any source file changes, every object file is out of date".  The second says the same about executables.

`make` knows how to build an executable direct from a source file; you don't need the object files as intermediaries.

I'd remove `$(OBJECTS)` from the `all` line (since you don't really need the object files).

Then you can remove the lines I identified and the commands that follow them (remove the last four non-blank lines shown in the question).

If you still want to be able to create all the object files, add:

```
objects: $(OBJECTS)
```

and use `make objects` to make them all.

FWIW: The compilation rule to create an object should specify `-c` directly and not include it in the `$(CFLAGS)` macro.  The compilation rule to build executables can (and should) then use `$(CFLAGS)` (as well as `$(LDFLAGS)` and maybe `$(LDLIBS)` too).

```
$(OBJECTS):
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(@:.o=.cpp) -o $@

$(EXECUTABLE):
    $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $@.cpp $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)
```

The `-o $@` in the object compilation line is largely unnecessary, at least in my experience.  The C compiler generates `$@` anyway.  It might matter if the source is not in the current directory, but that isn't the scenario you've got anyway.

And it is generally better to simply use the built-in rules so you don't have to get the arcane incantations like `${@:.o=.cpp}` correct.  With most versions of `make`, the built-in rules will be very similar to what I showed (use `make -p` to find out what they are with your `make`).  And GNU `make` has the modern rules using `%.o: %.cpp` notation whereas the code shown does not assume that.

Comment: Good note about the location for the `-c` flag and use of `$(CFLAGS`). Use of `$*` in a static rule always catches me off-guard though (especially since it depends on "recognized suffix"es).

Comment: @EtanReisner: I think you're probably right; it would be better to use `$@` here.

Comment: `$@.cpp` works for the executable but not for the object file. That needs `$(@:.o:.cpp)` or similar (since you can't use prerequisite variables as you don't have any). Static pattern rules would help with this.

Comment: @EtanReisner: Under-caffeination — a deadly state for programming.  Doubly so when the code isn't testable (or, at least, isn't tested).