# Makefile: compile all c source files at once

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have source tree like this.

```
├── Makefile
└── src
    ├── bar.c
    └── foo.c
```

I know i could compile all source codes in src using

```
src/%.o: src/%.c
   gcc -c -o $@ $<
```

but i've tried this and get this result..

```
SRCS = $(wildcard ./src/*.c)
OBJS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SRCS))
all: $(OBJS) main

main:
        gcc $(OBJS) -o main

$(OBJS): $(SRCS)
        gcc -c -o $@ $<
```

and get this result.

```
gcc -c -o foo.o ./src/foo.c
gcc -c -o bar.o ./src/foo.c
```

why gcc -c -o bar.o ./src/foo.c ?
even it has same format as a

```
src/%.o: src/%.c
   gcc -c -o $@ $<
```

Comment: Because it doesn't have the same format. Expand `$(OBJS)` and `$(SRCS)` in your makefile and you get `foo.o bar.o ...: ./src/foo.c ./src/bar.c ...` which make understands as saying that *every* `.o` file has **all** the `.c` files as their prerequisites. So each one is built from the first prerequisite in the list which is `./src/foo.c`. The pattern rule `src/%.o: src/%.c` doesn't work that way.

Comment: My answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31192185/258523), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31551042/258523) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28037184/258523) all mention this a bit too.